# thmtools declaration for theorem and proof.

Tags: formatting, thmtools

I'm using thmtools to specify the theorem and proof environments. The problem that arises is that I want my theorems stated in italics and my proofs in non-italic. The following is my initial setup:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=-6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    postheadspace=1em, 
    qed=$\blacksquare$, 
    headpunct={:}]{mystyle} 
\declaretheorem[name={Proof}, style=mystyle, unnumbered]{Proof}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\mdseries\bfseries, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={:}]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[name={Theorem}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{thm}
```

as with the bodyfont, I've declared the theorem statements to be italic. I have not done so for the proofs, nevertheless, both the theorem and proof are stated in italics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're declaring twice the style `mystyle`, once for `Proof` and second for `Theorem`. Only the last one is remmembered. You must change one of style names and apply the change is corresponding `\declaretheorem` definition.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=-6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    postheadspace=1em, 
    qed=$\blacksquare$, 
    headpunct={:}]{myproofstyle} %<---- change this name
\declaretheorem[name={Proof}, style=myproofstyle, unnumbered]{Proof}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt, 
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\mdseries\bfseries, 
    notebraces={(}{)}, 
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    headpunct={:}]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[name={Theorem}, style=mystyle,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Body of my first theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{Proof}
This proves my first theorem
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]